# How to make Varnish work with OwnCloud's non-standard session cookie

Tags: varnish, owncloud

I wish to deploy owncloud 9.x on two nodes behind a Varnish 3 server configured for round robin balancing.

By default my Varnish default.vcl cleans up all cookies except PHPSESSID.

I see that Owncloud session cookie name is not the usual PHPSESSID.

How can I change Varnish script accordingly?
or
How can I configure Owncloud to fallback to PHPSESSID?

Comment: You can change the VCL to accept that cookie name also. The name of the cookie is not relevant for Varnish or other proxy. Your backend dictates the name of the cookie and you should not change it's name in any intermediate steps

Comment: @matheuzzy unfortunately own cloud changes the cookie name for each session

Answer (score 1):

Since my varnish serves multiple hosts the only *solution* I've found is

```
sub vcl_recv {  
    if( req.http.host ~ "owncloud" ) {
        return(pass);
    }
}
```